# How to fix css font style to show properly in all browsers?

Tags: css

I currently use this code in **style.css** file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Frutiger; 
    src: url('fonts/frutiger.ttf');
}
```

It works fine in

- Chrome
- Firefox

but it doesn't work in

- Internet Explorer

I tried to add font in oet open embedded type with this line: line src: url('fonts/frutiger.oet'); to my code but  then it doesnt want to work in chrome either.

I don't know how to properly set fonts to be displayed in all browsers without any problems. Kindly let me know, my site url is www.virmodrosti.com

Comment: What version of Internet Explorer are you trying this with?

Comment: internet explorer 11

Comment: @techuser there are many online to create css file for the font try this one, 
https://www.web-font-generator.com 
https://www.fontsquirrel.com

Comment: AFAIK IE11 is more comfortable with ttf than with eot fonts. Anyway, you have `src: url('fonts/frutiger.ttf'), 
url('fonts/frutiger.eot')` in your stylesheet, which is not how you should invoke eot files. Use one of those online services to create the css instead.

Answer (score 0):

The newer bulletprof font syntax is:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'my-font'; 
    font-display: swap; 
    src: url('/fonts/my-font.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
         url('/fonts/my-font.woff') format('woff'); /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
}
```

The older bulletproof font syntax was:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'my-font';
  src: url('/fonts/my-font.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('/fonts/my-font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('/fonts/my-font.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('/fonts/my-font.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('/fonts/my-font.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('/fonts/my-font.svg#svgMyFont') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```